# Advertisement block changing

Tags: blocks

I have a Drupal 7 site, where there is a normal static block at the top of my content region. This is basically an advertisement with some full html content. Now I want to have a second similar block, and I'd like to keep them switching periodically somehow.

Before jumping on to coding something with javascript, I'd like to ask around to see if there is any easy solution for this, maybe a module for rotating ads?

(I know there are some themes that come with this feature out-of-the box, but I like my theme, so would not switch that for this minor thing)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched Google for ad modules or rotating ad modules?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that looks like most of them rotate a set of images, but I have blocks to rotate. I am now checking jcarousel, which is said to be able to work with any content type, but I have some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the right approach is not looking for something that changes blocks. I needed to define a content type, then create a view that lists my ads, and apply one of the numerous view-based carousels, like https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow